# Prove that if $Z(G) =\{e\}$, then $Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))=\{e\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

I know $Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))=\{e\}$ , then $Z(G)$  may not be identity.  As, for example, take $G = V$ (Klein's $4$-group). Then $\operatorname{Aut}(G)=S_3$. Hence $Z(\operatorname{Aut}(G))=\{e\}$ but $Z(G) =G$. (Here $Z(G)$  means center of $G$) My question is the converse of the result.  I know this is true but How can I proceed?  Any hint?

Comment: How do you know this is true? Why can't you write down the argument that convinces you?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If $\phi$ is our central automorphism, then since it commutes with the conjugation automorphisms, we have for all $g,h\in G$, $$\phi(ghg^{-1})=g\phi(h)g^{-1}$$

Since $\phi$ is an automorphism, we can expand and rearrange to obtain, for all $g,h\in G$:$$\big(g^{-1}\phi(g)\big)\phi(h)\big(g^{-1}\phi(g)\big)^{-1}=\phi(h)$$

So for any fixed $g$, the element $g^{-1}\phi(g)$ commutes with every element in $\phi(G)=G$, so since $Z(G)={e}$, we have that $g^{-1}\phi(g)=e$ for all $g\in G$.

Thus, our central automorphism $\phi$ must be the identity.

Comment: Then every central automorphism is identity.  Then how can u say all automorphism belonging to centralizer is identity?

Comment: A central automorphism is just what I am calling an element of the centre of $Aut(G)$, so we can deduce $Z(Aut(G))=e$.

Comment: Thanks,,  I understand